# Installing Swift on Freebsd Cannot Make LLVM

Tags: freebsd, make, llvm

I am attempting to build Swift using the new port on FreeBSD 10.2, however, make throws the following error :

> llvm38-3.8.0_3 is marked as broken: LLDB does not build with Python 3.

What do I need to do to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you can live without `lldb` you can run

```
cd /usr/ports/llvm38
make config
```

and remove the lldb flag.

> LLDB Install lldb, the LLVM debugger (ignored on 9.x)

I don't know if swift needs `lldb` to work.

But as long as the port is broken you need to deactivate it, until it will be fixed, which will happen at some point.

Comment: As far as I know, you need lldb for the REPL support. on macOS, lldb --repl invokes swift repl.